# Disable mouse moving to center of newly focused window when Alt-Tab/Alt-Esc

Tags: windows-10

I have enabled the "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse" setting in Windows 10 in the Ease of Access Center. I love the function but it automatically snaps the cursor to the center of the next active window when Alt+tabbing. I want to disable the cursor moving to the center of the active window.
The reason for this is because I want to scroll through the windows underneath my mouse (while activating the windows beneath them) by Alt-Esc. I have a 4k tv I use as a monitor and windows are everywhere but in an organized manner. I tried doing registry edits but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I am confused, do you want activate under the mouse or not.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.